# Will it be okay if I increase the unit scale in the world?

Tags: modeling

When simulating, someone tell us to increase the size.
It's hard to make it big. Because it's hard to match the size.
So I was wondering if raising the unit scale in the world has the same effect as just raising a character.
Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the world's unit scale has absolutely no effect other than changing how values are displayed in Blender.

Comment: I see. That's unfortunate. Thank you.

Comment: If it helps, you can always parent your objects to one main parent and scale this one. You can even use a cube, set it to wire display only and disable it in rendering, and go in edit mode to make it contain all your objects. That way in object mode, when selected, you will be able to see the "Dimensions" or your stuff.

Comment: That's a good idea. But I'll use a different method. When I made the character, I scale it five times. I will set the scale value to 0.2 in the world. I think this method is comfortable for me. Thank you for your answer.